# How to get my Weibo(China SNS) tweet list using developer api in the java?

Tags: java, timeline, weibo

I want to get my Weibo (www.weibo.com - china sns) tweet list by api.

I am using https://code.google.com/p/weibo4j/ library.

But their sample source only contains web auth.

If i want to their accessToken, their sample source shows tutorial using web browser.

```
System.setProperty("weibo4j.oauth.consumerKey", Weibo.CONSUMER_KEY);
System.setProperty("weibo4j.oauth.consumerSecret", Weibo.CONSUMER_SECRET);
Weibo weibo = new Weibo();
RequestToken requestToken = weibo.getOAuthRequestToken();
...
BareBonesBrowserLaunch.openURL(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
```

I want to login weibo api using my account directly and get my timeline post list.

But I think their document does not contain this method. Is anybody already resolved its problem?

So i want to code library for using weibo api as below code.

```
Weibo weibo = new Weibo();
weibo.setUserAndPassword('john', 'johnpassword'); // weibo4j does not support this method.
....
Paging pag = new Paging();
pag.setSinceId(3343021761165196l);
pag.setCount(200);
List<Status> statuses = weibo.getUserTimeline("john", pag);
```

Is there any java library for using weibo api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think there aren't any library can get weibo timeline via plaint username and password!**

A short history:
Weibo api has two version, namely V1 and V2.
In V1 version api, they actually support this kind of login, check this [example](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/Statuses/show).
However, after V2 version api was created, all app must use oauth2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In http://open.weibo.com/wiki/Statuses/show?sudaref=stackoverflow.com, there is function weibo.setUserId('XXX');. But i can not find setUserId in the weibo4j packages. Is it upgraded?

Comment: Yes. In this page http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3, they also stated that new app *must* use oauth2.0 and v2 version api.

Comment: So if I want to get access token with username and password, the guideline is http://open.weibo.com/wiki/OAuth2/access_token, is it right? Is this api service already started?

Comment: You can *only* get access token with AppKey and AppSecret! In order to get access token, you need to call to api: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/Oauth2/authorize and  http://open.weibo.com/wiki/OAuth2/access_token